# Under what condition is a linear mapping contractive in the sup-norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, linear-transformations, contraction-operator

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear mapping represented by the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

Then $T$ is said to be contractive in the sup-norm if for all $x,y$

$$\|Ax-Ay\|_\infty \leq l\|x-y\|_\infty$$
$l \in [0,1)$

Are there other sufficient condition that characterizes for when $T$ is contractive in the sup-norm? I am thinking along the line of $\|A\|_\infty < 1$ where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the sup matrix norm. I would be glad if someone can provide a reference to these results

Can someone offer an example of such a linear map?

Comment: The $\|.\|_\infty$ norm means that $\|A u\|_\infty = \sup_{k} |\sum_{m=1}^n A_{k,m} u_m|$ so you can look at the rows of $A$ one by one

Comment: The condition $\|A\|_\infty<1$ is precisely equivalent to $A$ being a contractive linear mapping in the sup-norm.  What more are you looking for, then?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know this result, I have very little experience with matrix norms in general, for me that was just a reasonable guess. Do you know if there is a reference to this result? Perhaps in some linear operator text because so far I have not been able to locate it

Comment: No, I don't have a reference for this particular result, nor do I have a reference for the result described in the first comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof:** (of your guess)

Note that
$$
\|Ax-Ay\|_\infty \leq l\|x-y\|_\infty \quad \forall x,y \in \Bbb R^n \quad \iff\\
\|A(x-y)\|_\infty \leq l\|x-y\|_\infty \quad \forall x,y \in \Bbb R^n \quad \iff\\
\|Ax\|_\infty \leq l\|x\|_\infty \quad \forall x \in\Bbb R^n \quad \iff\\
\frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty} \leq l \quad \forall x \in\Bbb R^n \quad \iff\\
\sup\left\{ \frac{\|Ax\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty} : x \in \Bbb R^n, x \neq 0\right\}\leq l  \quad \iff\\
\|A\|_\infty \leq l
$$
where the last equivalence is merely an application of the *definition* of $\|A\|_\infty$.

---

As is explained in [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm), the $\infty$-norm can be nicely characterized by
$$
\|A\|_\infty = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|
$$
which is to say that the norm is simply the maximum absolute row-sum.  So, in order to construct examples, it suffices to find vectors $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $\sum |a_i|<1$, and make those the rows of your matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I will find some examples of these matrices...

Comment: I'll add something about that

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow \forall k, \sum_{m=1}^n |A_{k,m}| = \|A_k\|_{1} \le 1$ @BeachedWhale (where $\mathbb{R}^n,\|.\|_1$ is the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $\mathbb{R}^n,\|.\|_\infty$)

Comment: What if $x,y$ are restricted to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $y \neq 0$